# Using $this when not in object context in

Tags: php, классы

Добрый день.
Имеется класс:

```php
class Hotel {

    protected $hotelName;
    protected $city;
    protected $countryCode;
    protected $address;
    protected $latitude;
    protected $longitude;
    protected $photo;
    protected $stars;
    protected $average;
    protected $hightlights;
    protected $description;
    protected $rooms;
    protected $url;
    protected $partnerName;

    // Свойство для доступа к защещенным полям класса. Для чтения.
    public function __get( $name ) {
        switch ( $name ) {
            case 'hotelName':
                return $this->hotelName;
                break;
            case 'city':
                return $this->city;
                break;
            case 'countryCode':
                return $this->countryCode;
                break;
            case 'address':
                return $this->address;
                break;
            case 'latitude':
                return $this->latitude;
                break;
            case 'longitude':
                return $this->longitude;
                break;
            case 'photo':
                return $this->photo;
                break;
            case 'stars':
                return $this->stars;
                break;
            case 'average':
                return $this->average;
                break;
            case 'hightlights':
                return $this->hightlights;
                break;
            case 'description':
                return $this->description;
                break;
            case 'rooms':
                return $this->rooms;
                break;
            case 'url':
                return $this->url;
                break;
            case 'partnerName':
                return $this->partnerName;
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // Свойство для доступа к защещенным полям класса. Для записи.
    public function __set( $name, $value ) {
        switch ( $name ) {
            case 'hotelName':
                $this->hotelName = $value;
                break;
            case 'city':
                $this->city = $value;
                break;
            case 'countryCode':
                $this->countryCode = $value;
                break;
            case 'address':
                $this->address = $value;
                break;
            case 'latitude':
                $this->latitude = doubleval( $value );
                break;
            case 'longitude':
                $this->longitude = doubleval( $value );
                break;
            case 'photo':
                $this->photo = $value;
                break;
            case 'stars':
                $this->stars = floatval( round( $value, 1 ) );
                break;
            case 'average':
                $this->average = floatval( round( $value, 1 ) );
                break;
            case 'hightlights':
                $this->hightlights = $value;
                break;
            case 'description':
                $this->description = $value;
                break;
            case 'rooms':
                $this->rooms = intval( $value );
                break;
            case 'url':
                $this->url = $value;
                break;
            case 'partnerName':
                $this->partnerName = $value;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

От этого класса наследуется еще один класс:

```php
class Booking extends Hotel {

    public function collect( array $data, $url ) {
        $this->hotelName = $data['hotelName'];
        $this->city = $data['cityName'];
        $this->countryCode = $data['countryCode'];
        $this->address = $data['address'];
        $coordinates = explode(',', $data['coordinates']);
        $this->latitude = $coordinates[0];
        $this->longitude = $coordinates[1];
        $this->photo = implode(';', $data['photos']);
        $this->stars = $data['rating'];
        $this->average = $data['average'];
        $this->hightlights = $data['hightlights'];
        $this->description = strip_tags( $data['description'] );
        $this->rooms = $data['rooms'];
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->partnerName = "Booking";
    }
}
```

Когда вызываю метод `collect` то выходит ошибка:
`PHP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: Hotel::$hotelName in /var/www/cli/Classes/Booking.php on line 6`

Comment: Есть предположение, что вы нам показываете не тот Hotel, который реально исполняется.

Comment: Почему это? У меня больше никаких классов нету кроме этих.

Comment: Потому что нигде не используется статический доступ, и hotelName должен быть доступен.

Comment: А как это реализовать, пример можно составить из моего класса?

Comment: Я про ту реализаацию, что у вас выше.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что поля родительского класса должны быть статические и открытые?

Comment: Нет, я имею в виду, что крайне маловероятно, что подобная ошибка возникает для приведенного кода в силу вышеописанных причин. Скорее всего, в редакторе у вас один файл, а исполняется другой.